# MongoDB: Nested query with arrays, and it's performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-scala

I have 2 collections on 2 separate DBs. Both store an array field. I plan to query both at once so that:

> All collection 1 documents that have elements [A,B] in their array
>   field and their _ids are present in collection 2's array field with a
>   specific document _id.

As an example:

docs (collection 1, DB 1):

```
[{"_id":ObjectId("doc1"), "array1":["A","B"]}, {"_id":ObjectId("doc2"), "array1":["A","C"]}]
```

user_docs (collection 2, DB 2):

```
[{"_id":ObjectId("usr1"), "array2": [ObjectId("doc1"),ObjectId("foo")]}, {"_id":ObjectId("usr2"), "array2": [ObjectId("bar"),ObjectId("baz")]}]
```

I need a query that given A,B and usr1, returns the 'doc1' object (because it has A,B in it's array1 field and usr1 has it in it's array2 field).

I obviously can fetch all docs having A,B in one query and all usr1's docs in another query and find the common elements at application level, but is there any better way of doing it using MongoDB?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok im not sure i understand exactly what your trying to do from your description. But i dont understand why you would query data across db's this just seems very heavy handed to me why cant you store both the data sets in the same db. You can always separate later if required? Im not sure this will solve your vague problem but it would be a good place to start.

best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to query MongoDB twice, since you have no possibility of a join. You will have to do it on application level. If you can denormalize, do it. Cash the needed data in a embedded doc, so that you can do one query only.

I think @Eamonn is right, that you shouldn't have to do a query across DBs.